# Copying Licence file to bin/Release/Publish

Tags: xml, publish, licensing, csproj

I'm trying to copy a .lic file to the bin/Release/Publish folder. I've tried CopyToOutputDirectory which works for placing the file in the regular bin folder under the project. The file to copy is in the root directory of the project and I've tried using None and Content as the build action in Visual Studio.

```
<None Include="umbracoForms.lic" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to sort this through our deployment process, added a script to copy the file from the solution over to the publish folder's bin. Used AzureDevOps with is copy build task which worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following lines from the .pubxml file and at that point the .lic files got copied back into the publish.zip:

```
<PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
<EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
<DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
<WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
```